# LinqToXsd Serialization gives duplicate (nested) root element

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, linq-to-xsd

I have a number of XSD's which have to be used as requests for web services. When I serialize the request to a string (or file), then the root element is always repeated as an xml element. Why is this? How can I prevent this?

I use LinqToXsd (nuget package) V2.0.2. with VS2013.

The XSD:

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:ns0="http://blah.com" targetNamespace="http://blah.com">
<xsd:complexType name="SomeValues">
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Value1" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xsd:element name="Value2" type="xsd:int" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
```

The resulting XML (as you can see, the root 'SomeValues' is repeated):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<SomeValues>
  <SomeValues xmlns="http://blah.com">
    <Value1 xmlns="">1</Value1>
    <Value2 xmlns="">2</Value2>
  </SomeValues>
</SomeValues>
```

And here is the serialization snippet:

```
private static string SerializeTest()
{
    var content = new SomeValues
    {
        Value1 = 1,
        Value2 = 2
    };

    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(content.GetType());

    using (var stringWriter = new StringWriter())
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stringWriter, content);
        return stringWriter.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Specify [XElement("tag name")] instead of [XmlArray("tag name")].

Comment: How would I do that when using LinqToXsd?